# How to Read from a text file and then Write to another in one Console application?

Tags: c#, file-io, console

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Alameer Ashraf\\Desktop\\data binding and I Ostreaming\\ResultFile.txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = fileInfo.CreateText())
        {
            FileInfo Teto = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Alameer Ashraf\\Desktop\\data binding and I Ostreaming\\WorkerTable.txt");
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Alameer Ashraf\\Desktop\\data binding and I Ostreaming\\WorkerTable.txt"))
            {

                string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                Console.WriteLine("<Name>");
                Console.WriteLine(columns[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("<" + "/" + "Name" + ">");

                Console.WriteLine("<ID >");
                Console.WriteLine(columns[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("<" + "/" + "ID " + ">");

                Console.WriteLine("<Number>");
                Console.WriteLine(columns[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("<" + "/" + "Number " + ">");

                Console.WriteLine("<Job>");
                Console.WriteLine(columns[3]);
                Console.WriteLine("<" + "/" + "Job " + ">");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

i failed to do what i have been explained ??
help please 
i want to read from a file , then write what i'm reading into another one by using the same application ,  can i do that ? 
i want to read an .csv file and  extract information from , then rewriting that information into another text file in the same console application , using IO File stream .

Comment: i'm not an experienced developer

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can't expect us to write your programs for you.

Comment: Post your code and explain what the exact problem you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\Alameer Ashraf\\Desktop\\data binding and I Ostreaming\\WorkerTable.txt")))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open ("C:\\Users\\Alameer Ashraf\\Desktop\\data binding and I Ostreaming\\ResultFile.txt", FileMode.Create)))
                { 
                    string line;
                    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "<Name>");
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, columns[0]);
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "</Name>");

                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "<ID >");
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, columns[1]);
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "</ID >");

                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "<Number>");
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, columns[2]);
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "</Number>");

                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "<Job>");
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, columns[3]);
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "</Job>");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void WriteAndPrint(StreamWriter writer, string line)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Although, I cringe at seeing what seems to be XML written directly to a file when [a perfectly good library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for interfacing with XML data exists in .NET. You should also probably look for a proper CSV parser, or write one yourself; it's not a very difficult specification to match.

Comment: Thank you very much , but the problem not solved yet 
because your code read and write from and to the same text file and that , do not achieve my goal !!

Comment: @AlameerAshraf All you had to do was switch out the file name. I did fix the code though.

Comment: Really Thank you very much , i'm really thankful to you